# Unable to run Serenity Selenium tests in GitLab

Tags: selenium, gitlab, google-chrome-headless, serenity-bdd

I am trying to run my Serenity Selenium tests in GitLab pipeline, but I'm getting DriverConfigurationError error

```
[main] INFO  - STEP FAILURE: net.thucydides.core.pages.WrongPageError: The page object class testing.pages.LoginPage could not be instantiated:
 Failed to instantiate page (net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver)
```

I have used below code for gitlab-ci.yml.

```
image: maven:3.5.3-jdk-8-alpine

stages:
  - test

variables:
  ENV: "qct"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode"

build:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome     
      alias: selenium
  script:
    - echo "Executing BDD scenarios with maven"
    - mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.options=src/test/resources/features/Login.feature -Denv=$ENV
  
  after_script:
    - rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
    - apt-get update
    - apt-cache gencaches
    - apt-get install -y zip unzip
    - zip -r serenity_report.zip ./target/serenity
    
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - ./serenity_report.zip
```

Serenity.properties

```
serenity.jira.workflow.active = false
serenity.logging = VERBOSE
serenity.jira.workflow = workflow.groovy
serenity.outputDirectory = target/serenity
serenity.restart.browser.for.each = NEVER
serenity.take.screenshots = FOR_FAILURES


#********************* GOOGLE-CHROME BROWSER ***********************#
webdriver.driver = chrome
webdriver.chrome.driver = src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe
headless.mode = true
chrome.switches = --homepage=about:blank,--no-first-run
ssl = --ignore-certificate-errors
restart.browser.each.scenario = true
chrome_preferences.default_directory = "src/test/resources/downloads"
chrome_preferences.profile_default_content_settings.popups = 0
chrome_preferences.pdfjs.disabled = true
restart.browser.each.scenario = true
report.customfields.environment = Integration
report.customfields.ApplicationVersion = 1.2.3
webdriver.wait.for.timeout = 8000
```

When I try to run these tests through JUnit Runner or Maven Command line, they work perfectly.
I'm assuming I need to either download chromeDriver in Docker, but not quite sure. Anyone has any idea, will be of great help or some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of reserach, I came up with below solution.

1. If we run the Chrome tests in headless mode, the browser will not be full screen. So, I have made the browser full screen.

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920,1080));
```

2. I have used markhobson/maven-chrome docker image which already has Java8/11/16, Selenium and ChromeDriver 91 installed. So, I have used WebDriverManager to run the Chrome tests.

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: markhobson/maven-chrome

stages:
  - test

variables:
  ENV: "QA"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  
build:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: true

  script:
    
    # Run your tests
    - echo "Executing BDD scenarios with maven"
    - mvn clean verify -Denv=$ENV 
       
   
  # Store artifacts
  artifacts:
    when: always
    name: "serenity"
    paths:
    - target/serenity/*
    expire_in: 24 h
```

Serenity.properties

```
serenity.jira.workflow.active = false
serenity.logging = VERBOSE
serenity.jira.workflow = workflow.groovy
serenity.outputDirectory = target/serenity
serenity.restart.browser.for.each = SCENARIO
serenity.take.screenshots = FOR_FAILURES


#********************* CHROME BROWSER ***********************#
webdriver.driver = chrome
headless.mode = true
webdriver.chrome.verbose = true
serenity.browser.maximized = true
chrome.switches = --no-sandbox,--disable-dev-shm-usage,--disable-popup-blocking,--disable-default-apps,--disable-extensions-file-access-check,--incognito,--disable-infobars,--disable-gpu
ssl = --ignore-certificate-errors
restart.browser.each.scenario = true
chrome_preferences.default_directory = "src/test/resources/downloads"
chrome_preferences.profile_default_content_settings.popups = 0
chrome_preferences.pdfjs.disabled = true
restart.browser.each.scenario = true
report.customfields.environment = Integration
report.customfields.ApplicationVersion = 1.2.3
webdriver.wait.for.timeout = 8000
```